# Membership Scheduled Reminders Failure

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I am trying to build a scheduled Membership Renewal Reminder to work but despite every effort I am not getting any reminder emails.   I think my parameters should result in a reminder email being fired off.  But nothing arrives.  Am I missing something?

To test my renewal reminder system, I set up a “Testing” membership (has $0 dues) for my Test User 3 days ago, which expired yesterday.

**MEMBERSHIP INFO**

> Member Since: 3/2/2023
>
> Start Date: 3/2/2023
>
> End Date: 3/3/2023
>
> No auto renewal

**REMINDER**
This is the first and only reminder in the system so the ID =1.  The reminder uses following parameters:

> Entity: Membership> Testing Membership> Renewal Reminder
>
> When (trigger date):  1 minute after Membership Join Date
>
> Record activity for automated mail: yes
>
> Repeat: Enabled, set for every 10 minutes until 7 days after
> Membership End Date
>
> Effective Start Date: 3/1/2023
>
> Effective End Date: 3/19/2023
>
> From Name: Reminder testing
>
> From email: info@mydomain.com
>
> Limit or Add recipients: Neither
>
> Scheduled Reminder Active: Yes

**TEMPLATE**

The template has only one token: {contact.first_name}

**SCHEDULED JOBS**

Furthermore I have added the following parameters to the Send Reminders scheduled job:

> Run frequency: Every time the cron job is run
>
> API Call: Job > send_reminder
>
> instanceId=1
>
> format=print
>
> Scheduled run date: blank
>
> Is this Scheduled Job Active: Yes

**JOB EXECUTION**

After manually executing the job I get the following success message:

Entity: Job Action: send_reminder

*Summary*

> Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Success (1)

*Details*

Parameters raw (from db settings):

> instanceId=1
>
> format=print
>
> sendmail=1

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):

> a:4:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:1:"1";s:6:"format";s:5:"print";s:8:"sendmail";s:1:"1";}

Full message: Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Success (1)

**SYSTEM**
CiviCRM 5.59.0

SendMail is tested and works fine.

CRON is working and runs every 16 minutes.

The destination email inbox is working fine.

Comment: Random thought #1: Maybe test with using a period other than 1 minute (eg 1 day).

Comment: Random thought #2: if you have access to the db tables then maybe worth taking a look at the civicrm_action_* tables in case anything leaps out from that

Comment: Random throught #3: strip out all your parameters from the Sch Job - confirm it runs, then start adding them back in (I just checked on a site that works and we have no parameters set for the job)

Comment: How do I get it to run without any parameters?  It needs to know when to run, and what to send.

Comment: compare with https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/job?action=update&id=9&reset=1 there is a dropdown to set the frequency, and to enable the Job